# how to set 2 word in 2 line in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview

I want to show text "abolfazl abbasi" in 2 line.
try

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abolfazl abbasi"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:lines="2" />
```

but not worked.

Comment: You can just write `abolfazl\nabbas` --> `\n` means new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backslash n `\n` and extracted resource in values/string.xml

values/string.xml :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="example">abolfaz\nabbasi</string>
</resources>
```

Your layout :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/example"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:lines="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` is useful, here is my tested image:
[image]

and here is the xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abolfazl\nabbas"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:lines="2" />
```

if still failed, maybe the `textview` widget is constrained by other widgets, please check whole layout file.